# Is there a version of subRegex which supports PCRE?

Tags: regex, haskell, posix, pcre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [haskell regex substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847475/haskell-regex-substitution)

I need to use [`subRegex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/0.92/doc/html/Text-Regex.html) but it seems to only work for Posix regular expressions.  Is there something that does the same thing but works with PCRE instead, or is there some setting I can change to make it work with PCRE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I maintain those modules.  The [regex-compat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat) module that provides Text.Regex is the compatibility that provides the "ancient" API that I superceded.

The new system, which also underpins regex-compat, has the API in [regex-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base).  This only defines the API, the implementation usually comes from regex-posix, [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre), or regex-tdfa.  The regex-compat uses regex-posix which agrees with the "ancient" API it preserves.  The [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre) module wraps PCRE itself.  The PCRE library is also wrapped by [pcre-light](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-light).

Substitution and replacement are not covered by any of these modules.  There are too many possible ways to want to store and process the text to cover everyone's needs.  The subRegex exists in Text.Regex merely because the "ancient" module had it.  The [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/latest/doc/html/src/Text-Regex.html#subRegex) for subRegex uses the regex-base API and can likely be tweaked for the regex-pcre backend instead of regex-posix.  The whole subRegex routine is less than a screen of code, so making a version perfect for your needs is going to be your best solution.

Note: If you run into any problems with the regex-* packages then I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a hand converting it to PCRE? What's the PCRE equivalent of `mkRegex`?  Is `matchAllText` still going to work?

Comment: @Chris: Since this tends to come up every now and then, perhaps you could add some documentation to this effect to the regex packages -- i.e. explaining why substitution is not provided, and providing some sample tweakable code to get folks started in rolling their own?

Comment: @Nick: Everything imported from regex-base API works the same for regex-posix and regex-pcre.  The difference is merely the type and styles of configuration options which is very backend specific.

Comment: @sclv: More documentation for regex-* will be forthcoming during the winter holidays.  And perhaps a new major version of regex-tdfa.