# How to find and replace unicode chars in Haskell?

Tags: regex, haskell, unicode

I have a unicode file containing a (Swedish) wikipedia article in MediaText markup. I want to clean it from all markup. In certain cases I want to extract text from the markup tags, such as the link titles from hyperlinks (like a simplified [wikiextractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor)).

My approach is to run a set of regex'es over the file to remove markup. In the link-example, I need to replace `[[link]]` with `link`. I manage to fix this well with a regex as long as the text does not contain unicode chars such as `ö`.

Example of what I've tried:

```
ghci> :m +Data.Text
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "\\[\\[([() a-zA-Z]*)\\]\\]") "Se mer om [[Stockholm]]" "\\1"
"Se mer om Stockholm"
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "\\[\\[([() a-zA-Z]*)\\]\\]") "Se mer om [[Göteborg]]" "\\1"
"Se mer om [[G\246teborg]]"
```

Why does this not work? How can I make the regex engine realize that `ö` is indeed a normal letter (at least in Swedish)?

**Edit:**
The issue seems to not really sit in the pattern, but in the engine. If i allow all characters except `q` in the link text, one could expect `ö` to be allowed. But not so...

```
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "\\[\\[([^q]*)\\]\\]") "[[Goteborg]]" "\\1"
"Goteborg"
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "\\[\\[([^q]*)\\]\\]") "[[Göteborg]]" "\\1"
"[[G\246teborg]]"
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "ö") "ö" "q"
"q"
ghci> subRegex (mkRegex "[ö]") "ö" "q"
"\246"
```

The problem seems to arise specifically when using character classes. It matches `ö`fine on its own.

Comment: What libraries are you using? Your Göteborg regexes give me `ReturnCode 17,"illegal byte sequence"` when I attempt them. In any case, the [POSIX regex spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09) says "Matching [is] based on the bit pattern used for encoding the character.... [I]f a character set contains two or more encodings for a graphic symbol... no attempt is made to search for any other representation of the encoded symbol. If that is required... specify equivalence classes containing all variations of the... symbol." Maybe that's it?

Comment: I used the `regex-compat` library, which conatins the `subRegex` function. I have swedish keyboard settings on my ubuntu. You can see that Haskell has recognised it as unicode point 246, correctly. I would not expect character classes to be the problem, since the negated char class pattern didnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now decided to go with Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy as suggested in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847475/haskell-regex-substitution/33253831#33253831) written by the author. It solves my problem.

Thus, the solution becomes

```
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy> :set -XFlexibleContexts
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy> :set -XQuasiQuotes
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE.Heavy> gsub [re|\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]|] (\(firstMatch:_) -> firstMatch :: String) "[[Göteborg]]" :: String
"G\246teborg"
```

Unfortunately I still don't know why the POSIX backend cannot handle this, but the PCRE backend can.

Answer (score 0):

To find and replace unicode characters in Haskell we can use the [`streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit) function, with [Megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) parsers for the pattern matching (instead of regex). The Megaparsec [`letterChar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Char.html#v:letterChar) parser will match all Swedish letters.

```hs
:set -XOverloadedStrings
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Void

let wikilink :: Parsec Void T.Text [Char]
    wikilink = do
        _ <- chunk "[["
        fst <$> manyTill_ letterChar (chunk "]]")

T.putStr $ streamEdit wikilink T.pack "Se mer om [[Stockholm]]"
T.putStr $ streamEdit wikilink T.pack "Se mer om [[Göteborg]]"
```

```hs
Se mer om Stockholm
Se mer om Göteborg
```